# How to check for ROLE_ADMIN in Spring HttpSecurity for restful services?

Tags: spring-security

I want to secure a REST API with OAuth 2.0 and Spring Security. I'm using Spring Boot 2.

This is the configuration I've started with:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/v1/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN0", "123");
}
```

Currently, I'm able to access /v1/** with ROLE_USER. How can I restrict access to /v1/** for ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_123 but not for any other role?

Comment: Are you using formLogin? httpBasic? or others?

Comment: @Lim I am using OAuth2 with jwt that is configured in a different place where it supposed to be. Additionally I am using Spring Boot 2,hibernate 5 and Microsoft Windows 7,all these details are irrelevant to the question. The question is about how to restrict access to some endpoints for subset of roles. Currently `hasAnyRole` is not working because I cannot understand the syntax of that fluent API, should it be with `and()` or before `authenticated()` or I need a new `authorizeRequests()` or what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to not having `and()` between the `antMatchers`:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // ... here goes your custom security configuration
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()  // whitelist Swagger UI resources
            // ... here goes your custom security configuration
            .and()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()  // require authentication for any endpoint that's not whitelisted
            .and()
            .antMatchers("/v1/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN0", "123");
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `.antMatchers()` on the `.and()`